# How can I scale my imagePickerController camera so it fills the whole screen?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, cgaffinetransform

I have hidden my camera controls, but that leaves a big black space. To resolve this, I am looking to scale my camera so that it fills the whole screen. I don't know why I am not able to do this. This is my code. Cheers!

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView
self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the camera aspect ratio is 4/3, so you'll have to apply a transform scale in order to make the camera full screen.

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
let aspectRatio:CGFloat = 4/3
let scale = screenSize.height/screenSize.width * aspectRatio
self.imagePikerViewController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the camera aspect ratio is 4:3 you can't have a full screen camera.

You can however, stretch the image to fill the screen. But personally i won't recommend that, since the image will probably not look right. 
Although you can use AV Foundation, AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer in particular o achieve the same. you can refer these link 
1.https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html 
2.https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/ 
for more information.
Hope it helps... 
Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works in iOS 13.x and was tested with both an iPhone 6+ and an iPhone 11 Pro.

```
    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let cameraAspectRatio = CGFloat(4.0 / 3.0)
    let cameraImageHeight = screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio
    let offsetToCenter = screenSize.height - cameraImageHeight
    let scale = (screenSize.height + offsetToCenter) / cameraImageHeight

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        myPickerController.delegate = self
        myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
        myPickerController.showsCameraControls = false
        myPickerController.allowsEditing = false
        myPickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        myPickerController.cameraOverlayView = CameraOverlay(frame: vc.view.frame, delegate: self)
        currentVC.present(myPickerController, animated: true)
    }
}
```